# Porting OpenGL project from Visual Studio to Xcode

Tags: visual-studio, xcode, opengl, opengl-es

I'm in the process of converting/migrating a Visual Studio OpenGL project to an Xcode (iPhone) OpenGL project.

Do you have any experience or suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand the limitations of OpenGL ES 1.1 and the performance of the hw in the iPhone, ie one can't use glBegin/glEnd so all vertex data has to be passed as arrays and GLU things are missing. See [here](http://tinyurl.com/4a3jqb) for some performance stats.

If your OpenGL code is fairly straight forward Apple supplies a good template to get going with it. I have created a [screencast](http://blip.tv/file/1600554/) where I demo a AC3D lib, 15s in I start with a clean Xcode OpenGL ES project.

Comment: sorry no. I thought I could spare you all my funny swedish accent ;) I placed some yellow info items though...